# How to add module to top bar menu openerp

Tags: odoo

I want to add a new module to the top bar menu at openerp.

I don't know what exactly the name is, but it placed at the top of the openerp (next to the people who login). By default, the top bar menu contains Messaging, Sales, Project, Knowledge, Reporting, Settings.

I want to add my new module to that menu bar. Can I? And how can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoas Loing

You have to do nothing to define new menu on top, just define your menu item and do not give any parent of this menu, and define at least on child below this menu,

Hope this help